# How to create pretty URL's with a custom MVC Framework in PHP?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, frameworks, pretty-urls

So, I am beginning the process of coding a PHP application website, which will be coded in the MVC architecture,but would like to implement the method of using Pretty URL's with it.  Since I have never created my own Pretty URL code before, I'm not sure where to start.  In the past, I would use query string URL's(I think  that's the correct term to use) such as example.com/index.php?act=controller&sub=method&id=123456... With this website, I would prefer the URL's to be something more like example.com/controller/method/article-title/123456.  But, like I said, I'm not even sure of where to start.

How would I point the URL correctly if...
The method provided isn't found, is invalid, or not provided at all? example.com/controller/article-title/123456  (would  point  to example.com/provided-controller/default-method/page-title/123456

The method provided is found, is valid, and is provided, but no controller is found or is invalid or is not provided?  example.com/article-title/123456  (should point to example.com/default-controller/provided-method/123456)

I hope I am being clear on everything and that you get what I'm talking about.  Basically, I want to do something like the CodeIgniter URL Router system.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you writing your own MVC framework or using an extant one such as Yii?

Comment: How can the method be valid without the controller (class)???

Comment: Yes I am writing my own basic MVC framework... hence the word "custom" in the title"

Comment: And the method could be valid if there's no controller.  Example:  When I used codeigniter, I would have my about and contact pages as methods of my default controller class... So in query string url's terms it would look like index.php?controller=default&method=about but it would be accessed through example.com/about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are not using an existing MVC framework that already gives you this, and that you want to create your own, my suggestion would be for you to implement a Front Controller. Here is a tutorial on how to do it: http://onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2004/07/08/front_controller.html

You can also take a look at an extremly simple example here: [What is a Front Controller and how is it implemented in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890200/what-is-a-front-controller-and-how-is-it-implemented-in-php)

Comment: Sorry for being so blunt, but are you sure this article is up to date and follows current web development trends?  It is from 2004, after all.

Comment: OTOH to be sincere, if you actually want to follow current web development trends you should be using a framework that already solves this... And you should probably be avoiding PHP: http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/