# php include file from other folder if not exist

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have different folder that have same file name and often same content

Is there a way to include file from other folders instead of creating the same file for those that have the same content?

Example of a directory structure

```
rome
  - index.php
  - detail.php
  - show.php
```

another folder

```
london
  - index.php (same content as rome/index.php folder)
  - detail.php (different content as rome/detail.php folder)
  - show.php (same content as rome/show.php folder)
```

Then london folder must include only detail.php that have different content from rome/detail.php and "index" and "show" must be loaded from rome folder

Now I create the file that have same content with this content

```
require ../rome/index.php
```

and work, but I have to create file for every folder and when I move or rename file in "rome" folder, I must do the same for each folder...

Server is linux, then I can use also a string in htaccess if possible....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to control all with [FrontController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890200/what-is-a-front-controller-and-how-is-it-implemented-in-php) - you can organise common responses for as so many actions as you want with exceptions you need. FrontController should be the central part of your application. It's implemented by [many frameworks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) and it's the way things like this should be done to not create and maintain many files.

Comment: FrontController seems to be a good solution, thanks...
But now I don't know if I have to rewrite my original code (rome folder in this case)... For example, I'm writing a simple frontcontroller in this way

        $path = "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";
        if (! file_exists ($path) )
        include str_replace("london" , "rome" , $path );

and I have error for the file that require a subcontent....

Comment: @FireFoxII Hello buddy. Can you write the whole code in new question or edit this one? Also, please add more detail about this error (traceback).

Comment: Thanks, I open here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41848860/php-create-front-controller-to-include-file-from-other-folder-if-not-exist

Answer (score 0):

Try with this root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# But not '/rome/'
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/rome/
# Rewrite to '/rome/...' if exist
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/rome/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(.+)$ /rome/$1 [L]
```