# php create front-controller to include file from other folder if not exist

Tags: php, .htaccess, front-controller

I'm creating a php front-controller because I need to include file from other folders instead of creating the same file for those that have the same content

Example of a directory structure

```
rome
  - index.php
  - detail.php
  - show.php
```

another folder

```
london
  - index.php (same content as rome/index.php folder)
  - detail.php (different content as rome/detail.php folder)
  - show.php (same content as rome/show.php folder)
```

Then london folder must include only detail.php that have different content from rome/detail.php and "index" and "show" must be loaded from rome folder

And this is my htaccess / front-controller

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule . /front-controller.php [L]
```

**front-controller.php**

```
path = "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}"; 
if (! file_exists ($path) ) include str_replace("london" , "rome" , $path );
```

The now I have problem for that file that include other content...

For example, my rome/index.php have

```
include 'content/header.php'
```

And when I load london/index.php I have the error

```
'content/header.php' failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

EDIT

these are the error

```
Warning: require(content/php/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/debian/www/rome/content/php/start.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'content/php/config.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:') in /home/debian/www/rome/content/php/start.php on line 17
```

Comment: I have tried to reproduce the error but it works :D Can you print the path of the file you are trying to include?

Comment: In the original post I have added the error

Comment: Visit here if you can... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41970755/php-front-controller-to-include-file-from-other-folder-if-not-exist .. If you reproduce, you have the same error