# PHP front-controller to include file from other folder if not exist

Tags: php, .htaccess, front-controller

I'm creating a php front-controller because I need to include file from other folders instead of creating the same file for those that have the same content

Example of a directory structure

```
[root]
  - start.php
  [rome]
     - index.php
     [subfolder]
         - page.php
  [london]
     (no file)
```

Here contents of the file

**index.php**

```
require '../start.php';
```

**start.php**

```
require 'subfolder/page.php';
```

And rome/index.php show page.php correctly...

Now in london folder, these are htaccess / front-controller

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule . front-controller.php [L]
```

**front-controller.php**

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
if (! file_exists ($path) ) include str_replace("london" , "rome" , $path );
```

When I call london/index.php, response is

```
Warning: require(subfolder/page.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ...

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'subfolder/page.php'
```

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your question (because i'm drunk ), but include paths are relative to the current file you are in. So make sure all of your includes are like `require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '../blah'`. Basically just use direname and the `__FILE__` constant to create absolute paths based on the current file

Comment: I guess you can't really call them absolute paths if they are based on the current file though. So ... relative paths based on the current file

Comment: I can't use absolute path because if London have own **subfolder/page.php** , i want that is used this file... With absolute path I always use **subfolder/page.php** of Rome folder... And I don't want this... 
P.S. sorry for my english

Comment: My advice: output the contents of $path and see what is there.

Comment: Why this? Path is always www/root/london/index.php