# I want to hide any request on the following php file to www.prismile.com/

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have done like

```
<IfModule>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/index.php$ http://www.prismile.com/ [R,NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^/corporate_philosophy.php$ http://www.prismile.com/ [R,NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^/search.php$ http://www.prismile.com/ [R,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

but it showing me message like

> Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, [no address given] and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

please help me to get it resolved. Thanks

Comment: For this kind of task people uses front controller and redirect every request to it, for example index.php.

Comment: @AbhishekGurjar could you please explain how can i acheive this?

Comment: It is broad question you have to create a index.php file which will include your pages as per request for ex. [see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890200/what-is-a-front-controller-and-how-is-it-implemented-in-php)