# How to find directories of a website using php?

Tags: php

I am making a SEO project using PHP where I need to crawl every pages/directories of a website. But for this, I have to know or list all the directories of that website. Is it possible?
Can we do it with PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. HTTP provides no way for a client (regardless of the programming language it is written in) to ask for directory listings.

This is why search engines [crawl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler) links and make use of [sitemaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps).

A PHP program could inspect the directory structure of the file system of the computer it is running on, but even that wouldn't give you a good view in the general case as most websites are not simply a bunch of files served up by mapping URLs directly onto a filesystem (for example, [the Front Controller design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890200/what-is-a-front-controller-and-how-is-it-implemented) is quite common).