# Cant connect html to external css

Tags: html, css

So im using template that is using internal css, and im going to move the css so it will be external css

this is my head script

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>Bootstrap CRUD Data Table for Database with Modal Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Varela+Round">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

im unable to use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">`, and its not underlined in my VScode.

and this is my folder structure

[image]

Comment: Why are you unable? Anything not working when you place that line in your markup? Does that file exist?

Comment: Could you place a small screenshot of your file/folder structure

Comment: @naveen im edited my question and there is my folder structure

Comment: _"and this is my folder structure"_ - what you are showing us there is a template file, so likely that does not get requested directly? What _URL_ are you actually using on the client side to request the page?

Comment: Looks like Laravel? Please edit your tag and name the PHP framework you are using. It will give more visibility to the laravel experts. Also elaborate a bit more. I thought it was just `html/css`

Answer (score 1):

A simple HTTP server will map URLs directly onto the filesystem. So if you ask for `http://example.com/foo/bar.html` it will look for a file at `C:\my webserver/web root/foo/bar.html`.

You have placed your stylesheet in a directory named *views*. This implies you are using some kind of framework which doesn't operate so simply. Typically it will use [the front controller pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890200/what-is-a-front-controller-and-how-is-it-implemented) and do things like placing the main content of a page in *views* and then wrapping it with standard headers and footers from a *layout*.

Systems like this aren't designed to handle stylesheets placed in *views*. You need to figure out how your system expects static files to be handled (commonly they are placed in a directory called *static* or *public*) and how to determine the URL for them.

The documentation for the framework you are using would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Check the relative path of the css file .
If you want to move one directory up then use `../` or if you want to locate the file in current directory then use `./`